# How to center image horizontal for all screen size in xamarin ios native

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to center image horizontally. 
Here is my activity :
[image]

As above you can my storyboard. There are two images. 1st Image in background which cover whole screen and that's perfect for all devices. `Now i have other image which you can see horizontally center and its work fine with iphone 6s plus`. But when i have `checked with iphone5 and X this image its not in horizontal center.`

I have used auto layout .

Here is the constraints:

[image: Constraints]

How to set this image horizontal center for all screen size ? and also how can i give padding top same for all device screens size ?

Comment: Please show us the constraints on the Image

Comment: @ColeXia added.

Comment: I can't see  `Align CenterX` constraint on image, it helps the view horizontally center.

Comment: You just need to set top, CenterX ,width,height constraint on image.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Can you guide me how can i assign center X constraint ? I have just started development of ios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to [Center Constraints](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/user_interface/designer/designer_auto_layout/#Center_Constraints)

Drag the square handle to the vertical Center green line of superView,as illustrated by the screenshot below

[image]

Comment: I have tried same thing but still i cant see image in horizontally center.

Comment: Did you delete the constraint you set before, just need to set `top, CenterX ,width,height` constraint on image.

Comment: Yes.Now its shows -> `Horizontal Alignment - loginBackgroundImage.Center X =  Logo.Center X`

Comment: It must be `loginBackgroundImage` doesn't fill the superview.  Set top, bottom,leading,trailing to `0`  on loginBackgroundImage.

Answer (score 0):

I center image in this way:

[image]

And as I look is easier to make storyboard in Xcode and then copy to xamarin project.

--EDIT--

In your storyboard add image on center of view and click on image and then in the Constraint Edit Mode:

[image]

Next on the center of image you will have pin spacing

[image]

And move this pin to the horizontal and vertical line. All the time look at the properties Constraints

[image]

Then you need to add spacing with one of the side. I add on the right:

[image]

After this you need to set value of space. I use 10

[image]

[image]

After all of this steps i have this constraints:

[image]

Sometimes I have to uninstall and install again app on simulator or phone to see changes.

Comment: How can i add this constraints in xamarin ?

Answer (score -1):

here is very simple solution

1. use frame mode

[image]

2. use arrange as in the image. choose all arrows on the left panel

[image]

Thus your image will be always in the center and resized for the device if you provide 3 sizes of images.